# Application of TryParse in C#

Tags: c#

When 'val' below is not a `bool` I get an exception, I believe I can use `TryParse` but I'm not sure how best to use it with my code below. Can anyone help?

```
checkBox.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(val);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

The code is as follows to determine whether the string `val` is a valid Boolean value and use it to set the `Checked` property if so. You need to decide what action you would take if it does not represent a valid value.

```
bool result;
if (bool.TryParse(val, out result))
{
    // val does represent a Boolean
    checkBox.Checked = result;
}
else
{
    // val does not represent a Boolean
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that if its not a valid boolean, you don't want it checked:

```
bool result = false;
bool.TryParse(val, out result);
checkBox.Checked = result;
```

Comment: Joel - if TryParse failed checkBox.Checked would default to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool z = false;
if(Boolean.TryParse(val, out z))
{
  checkBox.Checked = z;
}
```

Just a note: Parse and convert are different operations and may lead to different results.

Answer (score 0):

bool isBool = false;

bool.TryParse( val, ref isBool );

```
if( isBool )    
{
   ///ok;

}
else
{
  // fail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends; if you want checkBox.Checked to be equal to true if val - if it is a string - parses to true then use the following:-

```
bool output;
checkBox.Checked = bool.TryParse(val, out output) && output;
```

If bool is not a string then you need to decide how to deal with it depending on its type, e.g.:-

```
checkBox.Checked = val != 0;
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers here already.

I will however add, do be careful with TryParse, because contrary to what its name indicates, it can infact still throw an ArgumentException!

That's one of my pet annoyances with .NET! :)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the following may also come in handy in this (or similar) cases...

```
bool myBool = val ?? false;
```

...which is the good old "null-coalescing operator" and quite nice.

Read more about it here if you are interested: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Just posted this same snippet for another question, but here is the code I use across projects for doing a much better job of handling booleans in all their assorted versions:

```
bool shouldCheck;
TryParseBool(val, out shouldCheck);
checkBox.Checked = shouldCheck;

/// <summary>
/// Legal values: Case insensitive strings TRUE/FALSE, T/F, YES/NO, Y/N, numbers (0 => false, non-zero => true)
/// Similar to "bool.TryParse(string text, out bool)" except that it handles values other than 'true'/'false'
/// </summary>
public static bool TryParseBool(object inVal, out bool retVal)
{
    // There are a couple of built-in ways to convert values to boolean, but unfortunately they skip things like YES/NO, 1/0, T/F
    //bool.TryParse(string, out bool retVal) (.NET 4.0 Only); Convert.ToBoolean(object) (requires try/catch)
    inVal = (inVal ?? "").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
    switch ((string)inVal)
    {
        case "TRUE":
        case "T":
        case "YES":
        case "Y":
            retVal = true;
            return true;
        case "FALSE":
        case "F":
        case "NO":
        case "N":
            retVal = false;
            return true;
        default:
            // If value can be parsed as a number, 0==false, non-zero==true (old C/C++ usage)
            double number;
            if (double.TryParse((string)inVal, out number))
            {
                retVal = (number != 0);
                return true;
            }
            // If not a valid value for conversion, return false (not parsed)
            retVal = false;
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) This doesn't answer the question that is asked here. 2) If you find yourself posting the same answer to lots of different questions you're doing something wrong.  Either the questions really are different and the answer doesn't apply to all of them (which is the case here), or the questions are duplicates and should just have all but one closed as a duplicate of the best one.

Comment: I think that this is a valid reply to the question. They asked why TryParse didn't work, I gave a routine that would do what they wanted. Perhaps I should have added the usage:
   bool shouldCheck;
   TryParseBool(val, out shouldCheck);
   checkBox.Checked = shouldCheck;